# Order of bits in reg declaration

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

If I need to use 4 8-bit numbers, I would declare the following reg:

```
reg [7:0] numbers [3:0]
```

I'm quite confused about the difference between the first and second declaration ([7:0] and [3:0]). In what order should they come? Does first one stay for the size of a number while the second is for the number of numbers, or vice versa? And, does [7:0] or [0:7] give the right order?

Ordinary arrays of numbers look like this, for example:

```
0000
0110
0001
```

There are three 4-bit numbers (0000, 0110, 0001). We can access them by using array indices. So, accessing the first digit of the second number is done by something like this

```
a[0][1]
```

assuming that this array is stored in a variable `a`.

Returning to Verilog, how would accessing elements change if I would swap values in reg or declare them in reverse order ([0:7]), for example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `reg[7:0]` is an 8-bit "register", or variable
2. `reg[7:0] numbers[3:0]` is a 1-D array with 4 elements, named
   `numbers`, each of which is an 8-bit register
3. An element of `numbers` is accessed as `numbers[index]`
4. `numbers[i][j]` is a bit-select of `numbers[i]`. It accesses bit
   `j` in the `i`th element of `numbers`
5. As toolic says, it's more conventional for array indices to be
   numbered `[lsb:msb]`, but there's no good reason for this.

When assigning two objects, bits are copied left-to-right, as for VHDL.

Verilog has (very) poor checking of bit and part selects and array indexes. See the code below.

```
module top;
   initial
     test;
   task test;
      reg[3:0] a[0:1];
      reg[0:3] b[0:1];
      reg[2:5] c[0:1];
      begin
       a[0] = 4'b1101;
       a[1] = 4'b0110;
       a[2] = 4'b0001;                      // error, but not caught by Verilog

       $display("a[2] is %d", a[2]);        // modelsim produces no warning, prints 'a[2] is x'
       $display("a[0][4] is %b", a[0][4]);  // modelsim warns, and prints 'a[0][4] is x'

       $display(                            // produces '1.1.0.1'
         "a[0][3:0] is %b.%b.%b.%b", a[0][3], a[0][2], a[0][1], a[0][0]);

       b[0] = a[0];                         
       $display("b[0] is %d", b[0]);        // produces '13'
       $display(                            // produces '1.1.0.1'
         "b[0][0:3] is %b.%b.%b.%b", b[0][0], b[0][1], b[0][2], b[0][3]);

       c[0] = a[0];                         
       $display("c[0] is %d", c[0]);        // produces '13'
       $display(                            // produces '1.1.0.1'
         "c[0][2:5] is %b.%b.%b.%b", c[0][2], c[0][3], c[0][4], c[0][5]);
     end
   endtask
endmodule
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that syntax can be used to declare 4 8-bit numbers, however it is more conventional for 0 to be left of the colon for the number of words:

```
reg [7:0] numbers [0:3]
```