# Accessing register values in verilog

Tags: verilog, fpga

I initialize a register

```
reg[1:0] yreg;
```

and manipulate it a bit, i.e., value from prev. iteration of program is shifted to 1 spot when I add in the new value in the 0 spot

```
yreg = SIGNAL; //here SIGNAL is an input to the program
```

And then I want to access the values at the 0 and 1 spots in the register later for a calculation. How can I do this? My initial reaction was `yreg[0]` and `yreg[1]` (I normally program in python =) but this is producing an error (line 35 is the line of code that has `yreg[0]` and `yreg[1]` in it):

```
ERROR:HDLCompiler:806 - "/home/ise/FPGA/trapezoid/trapverilog.v" Line 35: Syntax error near "[".
```

My assumption when I saw this was that it's not the right syntax to use the brackets to access a certain index of the register. How do you properly access the information in an index of a register? I'm having trouble finding information on this.

Sorry for the probably ridiculous question, this is my first time ever using verilog or FPGAs in general.

### Full Code

```
module trapverilog(
    input CLK,
    input SIGNAL,
     input x,
    output OUT
    );

reg[1:0] yreg;
float sum = 0;

always @(posedge CLK)
begin
    yreg = SIGNAL; //should shift automatically...?
    sum = ((reg[0] + reg[1])*x/2) + sum; //this is effectively trapezoidal integration
    OUT = sum;
end

endmodule
```

Comment: Can you give more details on your code and the error syndrome?

Comment: I would love to help but the question is unclear, consider rewriting to describe the error and what do you want to achieve and what you've done so far.

Comment: @RaZ I added the error information. Is it more clear now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a fundamental misunderstanding of how Verilog signals work.

By default, all Verilog signals are single bits. For example, in your code, `SIGNAL`, `x`, and `out` are all one bit wide. They cannot store a number (other than 0 or 1).

Specifying a width when you define a signal (like `reg [1:0] yreg`) controls how many bits are used to represent that signal. For instance, `yreg` is a two-bit signal. This does not mean that it "shifts automatically"; it just means that the signal is two bits wide, allowing it to be used to represent numbers from 0 to 3 (among other things).

I would strongly advise that you work through a course in digital electronics design. Verilog programming is *very* different from procedural programming languages (such as Python), and you will have a hard time making sense of it without a solid understanding of what you are actually building here.

Comment: How can you make `x` and `out` longer than 1 bit?

Comment: The same way as you'd make another signal into a bus: `output [31:0] out`. Or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16762167/verilog-order-of-reg) using brackets to get a certain index of a register is correct. I just forgot to call the variable properly - I was calling `reg[0]` instead of `yreg[0]`. Changing this fixed the error.